# Clone Ubuntu with openssh-server, Still asking for password

Tags: 12.04, server, ssh, security, clone

I have a Ubuntu virtual machine with ssh installed. (Ubuntu 12 with GUI)

- I clone it and renew the clone IP address.
- I want that the Master can have ssh to the clone without asking password.
- I had set `id_dsa.pub` and `authorized_keys` in the clone machine.

However it still ask me password when I try to ssh from the master machine to the clone machine.

Can I have any suggestion? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to ssh with the -v flag and see what the identification error is.

```
ssh -v username@destinationIP
```

When you cloned the machine, the program may have regenerated the MAC address in the clone, so it's not recognized as the old one.

Also, I would advice to recreate the keys, not just copying them.

Comment: agreed. New IP and MAC would insist doing `ssh-copy-id` again.

Comment: Thank you Darent, however when I clone, I do not chose reinitialize MAC address option

Comment: I'm not sure about this, but if both client and server keep the same MAC address, communication will be a mess even with the ssh-copy-id, because both devices will appear as the same in the virtual network. You should reinitialize it in one of the machines, and then setup the keys anew.

Comment: The key is used to do ssh to other machine (not the clone one) which in ssh access to another machine (not the clone one) case is working properly. I think twice to regenerate the key

Comment: darent - I am following your advice to change the MAC of eth0. bkd.online - Now I had make different IP and MAC Address for both machine, can you explain more about the use of ssh-copy-id, please?

Comment: Once you have generated the id, you have to use something similar to this: "ssh-copy-id   -i   /home/youruser/.ssh/id_rsa.pub youruser@destinationip" Of course, change youruser with your actual username, and the name of the key (yours is dsa, not rsa i think). This will copy the id from the client to the server, so it should recognize you when you try to connect and won't ask you to log-in "manually" again.